# Node.js - passing values to other pages

Tags: javascript, node.js, curl, express

I'm trying to build a web service using node.js.
In this architecture, curl is used to POST data to the index.js app. The index.js app process the output and then it should pass the output to different pages.
For example, if the ID received is between 100-200 then push the ID to movies.html and so on.
Now I have been able to achieve the processing of POST request using CURL and node.js
I have no idea how to pass the data to other pages.
Here is my index.js code.

```
var http = require('http');
var qs=require('querystring');

var redis=require('redis').createClient();
console.log('Server Starting Now: ');
var count=0;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if(req.method=='POST'){
        count=count+1;
        var body="";

        req.on('data',function(data){
            body+=data;
        });

        req.on('end',function(){
           var post=qs.parse(body);
           console.log(post);
           res.write("Received");
           redis.lpush('XMLqueue',JSON.stringify(post));
        }); 
    }

}).listen(8124, "127.0.0.1");
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

How do I pass the data from this index.js page to other pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create handlers for other URLs which will respond with the data you want it to.

But actually, you seem to be confused by nodejs  and overall http server architecture a lot. I'd suggest you to read any "getting started nodejs" tutorial you find at Google and like to get the basics. Also, search for something like "nodejs express" and reading it will probably help you to get an easy start.